# How to compare date in Windows with C

Tags: c, date

Here is example how I do that in Linux, but in Windows I don't have `strptime` function anyone can help me solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

time_t to_seconds(const char *date)
{
    struct tm storage = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    char     *p       = NULL;
    time_t    retval  = 0;

    p = (char *) strptime(date, "%d-%b-%Y", &storage);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        retval = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        retval = mktime(&storage);
    }
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    time_t d1 = to_seconds("16-Jun-2015");
    time_t d2 = to_seconds("13-Jun-2015");
    if(d1 > d2)
    {
        printf("date 1 > date 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the cast `(char *) strp ...`? Also, `strptime()` is not standard.

Comment: I mean you don't need to cast `strptime()` to `char *` when it's available, and it's not on windows because it's not a standard function. And why that format, where are you getting the dates from? is it a file?

Comment: You are right... I c/p that function from net It works well on Linux but not on Windows. What can I use instead strptime() ?

Comment: It depends on why you want to use it, if you explain the use case I may help you. If you want write to me iharob@gmail.com

Comment: I sterted some open source project... I need to compare date and then sort lines inside array, project url: github.com/vforv/reminder

Comment: Where do the **date**s you want to compare come from?

Comment: Dates comes from text file...

Answer (score 0):

I made function for this, easy to use...

https://github.com/vforv/date-compare-C

Comment: Link-only answer are not the type of answers preferred at SO. At least you want to paste here the relevant part of the code along with an explanation, why it is answeing the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using .Net, I'd suggest:

1) Use [Convert()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx) or [DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

EXAMPLE:

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

2) Use [DateTime.Compare()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare the two DateTime values:

EXAMPLE:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
if (result < 0)
  Console.WriteLine("is earlier than");
else if (result == 0)
  Console.WriteLine("is the same time as";         
else
  Console.WriteLine("is later than";
```

Comment: I used VB.NET before, I know It is easy with .NET... But I am learning C now... :)

Comment: The question is about C explicitly.